# Close Modal Pop-up from alert

Tags: sharepoint-online, modal-dialog

I have a SP UIModal Pop-Up, in which I have a javascript code with alert. When I click OK in my alert, my pop-up should close...

Currently , I am closing the alert message, then I need to close the model dialog using the close [X] button. But my requirement is that the model dialog should close automatically once my alert is closed.

Comment: How to show alert when user click on  close [X]  ? can you share this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one of these functions after your alert:

```
window.frameElement.commitPopup() //passes SP.UI.DialogResult.OK back
window.frameElement.cancelPopUp() //passes SP.UI.DialogResult.Cancel back
```

Comment: Thanks . But this option is working fine **only in IE 8 + & Mozilla Firefox** , but _**not in Chrome & Safari**_. As MS prescribes only IE ,I'm escaped.  Is there any workaround to make it work for Chrome ?

Comment: Hmm that's strange. Just tested it in Chrome 52 and it works. Can't test Safari, though. Maybe there's another issue with your code.

Comment: If my code is having any other issue then how could it work perfectly in **IE & Firefox** ?? Also I had given alerts in ExecuteQueryAsync(); both succeeded & Failed.. When I run in chrome , my Query is failing and the alert under failed() is displayed.. But not in IE ...!!!! Miraculous Issue :D

Comment: How about you provide your code and I'll have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the element close[X], find the Id and call click event using jquery.
Something like

```
$('a[id="elementId"]').click();
```